# Display management in Gnome not working.

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora, gnome

I've just installed Fedora 22 (64bit). 
I have to monitors, one recognized as #1 (on my right) and one as #2 (on my left). Assigning the monitors to right hand side worked fine. 
I do though often times only use my #1 monitor and would like tu torn off #2 (so I dont accidentely switch over to the turned off monitor with my mouse).

Gnome's display options do offer me to turn off one monitor (also tried setting it to 'mirror'), but what happens is that I get thrown back to the login screen, login again and everything is as it was (both monitors activated).

I'm used to the neat Win+P feature of windows that lets me switch on and off me second monitor within seconds, can I configure Gnome / Fedora to do something similar? Or at least make the 'right click -> settings -> display -> etc' variant work?